# Determining if a set is a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I am currently on a linear algebra course, and I am having trouble understanding how to determine if a set of vectors is a vector space. How do I determine if $W$ is a vector space? I would like to understand how to make the proper proofs in order to get to the correct answer.

Let $W$ be the set of all vectors
\begin{bmatrix}
b−2d\\
5b+d\\
b+3d\\
d
\end{bmatrix}

where $b$ and $d$ are real.

Determine if $W$ is a vector space and check the correct answer below.

A. $W$ is not a vector space because it does not have a zero element.
B. $W$ is a vector space because it can be expressed as $W=\operatorname{span}\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$.
C. $W$ is not a vector space because it does not have additive closure.
D. $W$ is a vector space because it contains the zero element.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: consider
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
b−2d\\
5b+d\\
b+3d\\
d
\end{bmatrix}
=
b\begin{bmatrix}1\\5\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}
+
d\begin{bmatrix}-2\\1\\3\\1\end{bmatrix}
$$